# Set-ADObject - Custom field updates in ADLS

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So I know you can do this with LDIF, but trying to bring this into line with a PowerShell Script.

The object I want to change in this example is

```
Get-ADObject -Server 'localhost:389' -Filter {(name -like "name") -and (ObjectClass -eq "ont-configparameter")} -SearchBase 'CN=Bob,O=Bob1' -Properties "ont-configvalue" | Where-Object "ont-configvalue" -eq ".bob.bob.com"  | Select-Object Ont-configvalue | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize
```

This returns me the value `.bob.bob.com` as expected.

But I want to change this `ont-configvalue` to `".bob.bob.co.uk"` for the life of me I can't work out how to get `Set-ADObject` to do this.

I have about 20 of these to do, with different values and different params, so looking for genericish.

Comment: Look in the docs at the `-Add` parameter of `Set-ADOObject` as this allows you to modify values that aren't exposed as their own parameters

Comment: I've tried this, probably wrong as I don't quite understand the param.

Get-ADObject -Server 'localhost:389' -Filter {(name -like "name") -and (ObjectClass -eq "ont-configparameter")} -SearchBase 'CN=bob,O=bob1' -Properties "ont-configvalue" | where "ont-configvalue" -eq ".bob.co.uk"  | SELECT Ont-configvalue | Set-ADObject -add 'ont-configvalue'

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I haven't got an environment available at present where I can test these AD CmdLets and therefore the following code is unlikely to be spot on; but hopefully between the code and the commentary you should be able to find your way!

### Step 1

Identify the AD object you want to modify

```
$adObject = Get-ADObject -Server 'localhost:389' -Filter {(name -like "name") -and (ObjectClass -eq "ont-configparameter")} -SearchBase "CN=Bob,O=Bob1" -Properties "ont-configvalue" |
    Where-Object "ont-configvalue" -eq ".bob.bob.com"
```

### Step 2

Pass this identity in to the [Set-ADObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617254.aspx) CmdLet

```
Set-ADObject -Identity $adObject -Add @{ont-configvalue=".bob.bob.co.uk"}
```

This uses the `-Add` parameter:

> Specifies values to add to an object property. Use this parameter to add one or more values to a property that cannot be modified using a cmdlet parameter

However, the observant among you will no doubt have noticed that in this example we *know* that the `$adObject` has a value for `ont-configvalue` (we check the value in the `Get-`...

So we more likely want to use the `-Replace` parameter... which follows the same syntax, basically!

```
Set-ADObject -Identity $adObject -Replace @{ont-configvalue=".bob.bob.co.uk"}
```

Comment: I think, you've done it! I've had to make a minor change as predicted (Which I've edited above) and will do some more testing today. Thank you!!!

Comment: @RichardDakin what was your change? I should tweak the answer here to benefit future readers.

Comment: Sorry I should of said that. Was a little overexcited at seeing this working ;) - I amended the "ADD" function to -Replace @{'ont-configvalue' - PowerShell couldn't read it with the "-"